# How to properly use jQuery text() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

I would like to make an textarea and emoji list to put emojis into this textarea.
I am trying to make it with jquery.
I have an ul element like this:

```
<textarea id="TxtEmoji" class="textemoji" placeholder="Type a message here"></textarea>
button type="button" id="BtnEmoji" class="btnemoji">&#x1F600;</button>
<ul class="emoji-list">
                <li><img class="emoji" draggable="false" alt="" src="http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/16x16/1f33e.png"></li>
            </ul>
```

When I click on this "li" I would like to paste this image in textarea, so here is my function:

```
$(".emoji-list li").click(function () {  
    var mm = $(this).text();  
    var textVal = $("#TxtEmoji").val(); 
    $("#TxtEmoji").val(textVal + mm);     
});
```

But "mm" var is empty! Where I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The image is an image element, not a text node.

You could use `.html()` to get HTML source code for the image and put that in the text area.

You could use `.find('img').attr('alt')` to get the text alternative to the image (although you seem to have a non-printing character for yours).

You can't display an image in a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `html()` or `innerHTML` or `textContent()`.you will get the html data to display in text area. if you want to display image use `div` instead.get attribute scr like `$('img').attr('src');` and construct `img` tag with this to show in div.

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` function looks at text inside the tag. Your tag doesn't have text, it has an image with an `alt` attribute. Use this to get the attribute.

```
$(".emoji-list li img").click(function () {  
    var mm = $(this).attr("alt");  
    var textVal = $("#TxtEmoji").val(); 
    $("#TxtEmoji").val(textVal + mm);     
});
```

However in your example, the character is not printable so it will show up as a square box in most browsers.